# CodeIgniter Custom Router help

Tags: codeigniter, frameworks, url-rewriting, url-routing, codeigniter-url

Am very new to CI, So I want to know that one feature listed below will be done via CI Router, then How?

Feature:

Q1. I need to show my users profile in such a way that `mysite.com/johhn` `mysite.com/raju.radha`
`mysite.com/johhn1`.

Q2. Other Urls are `mysite.com/photo/3434`, `mysite.com/album/3443` etc etc.

I know this can be achieved by using `$route` . for the Q2 this is the solution

```
$route['photo/:num'] = "photo/photo_list";
$route['album/:num'] = "album/album_list";
```

and what is the solution for Q1??

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Route:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "profile/view/$1";
```

Controller:

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller {
    function view($username) {
        echo $username;
    }
}
```

Edit: Commenter made the great point that this will need to be the last route directive in the file to prevent it from overriding all of the other routing rules.

Comment: Worth noting you'll want to put this after any other routes you have defined as they run in the order they are defined so the original routes wouldn't run if this came first. But otherwise +1.

Comment: What will be the order when combine with my Q1 and Q2 ? any idea?

Comment: @coderex `$route['(:any)'] = "profile/view/$1";` will always be the last route in the router config file. The other two can go in any order as long as they appear before `$route['(:any)'] = ...`.

Comment: okey I understood. Hmm I need to preserver more n more keywords from usernames :) . thank you for your answer

Comment: Keep in mind that using a catch-all route will override the `404_override` route since all requests will be matched.  You'll need to manually account for 404 errors using `show_404()`.